# How to get property return type annotation?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm looking for a way to extract the return type annotation of a property from a class, e.g.:

```py
class Test:
    @property
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

print(return_type_extract(Test, 'foo')) # <class 'int'>
```

For standard methods this can be done like so:

```py
import inspect
class Test:
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

def return_type_extract(cls: type, method_name: str) -> type:
    method = getattr(cls, method_name)
    return inspect.signature(method).return_annotation

print(return_type_extract(Test, 'foo')) # <class 'int'>
```

This method however does not work for the `@property` decorator, as it raises an error inside `inspect.signature`. I've looked at an equivalent for properties in the `inspect` library, but so far no luck.

Comment: Note that the annotation for `cls` should probably be `type`, not `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the retrieved attribute is a property object, we can access its getter method (`.fget`) to get the underlying function.
Then we use `get_type_hints()` to extract the return type annotation from the underlying function.

Like this :

```
from typing import get_type_hints

class Test:
    @property
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 1

def return_type_extract(cls: object, property_name: str) -> type:
    property_obj = getattr(cls, property_name)
    if isinstance(property_obj, property):
        property_obj = property_obj.fget
    return get_type_hints(property_obj).get('return')

print(return_type_extract(Test, 'foo'))  # <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! Just a note you can also use `inspect.signature(property_obj).return_annotation` once you have the underlying function

Comment: @Mark those are not equivalent. Consider annotations future-import or just stringified annotation - `get_type_hints` will do its best to resolve them, but `inspect.signature` will return plain string. https://godbolt.org/z/7adsW91z9

Comment: That is interesting! I didn't realise this about `inspect.signature` but I see how each may have a use - certainly the `get_type_hints`  one seems like the more common use case.